# What is the difference between isometer and homorhythm?

Tags: rhythm

Wikipedia gives a complicated answer with no examples. Could someone explain in proper English?

Comment: Is isometer the same as isorhythmic?
I guess homometric is the medieval lauda long short pattern *) and isorhythmic is the homophone set of identical rhythmic values in all parts, especially the descant and tenor voices.   *) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Le_Jeune

Comment: Wikipedia thinks they're the same basic category;  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homorhythm  ,  and Dolmetsch seems to agree https://www.dolmetsch.com/defsi1.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the term "isometer" in music. There is a similar term: "isorhythm" which is a technique of using the same rhythmic structure, usually short 4-7 or so notes, against a fixed pitch-pattern. For example, using 4 notes such as C-A-G E (but not played as quietly as the original) with a rhythm of half-whole-half- whole-hole would lead to a 20 note repeating pattern. This was quite popular in the 1200-1400 period.

Homorhythm is often used to mean the same rhythm in all parts like block chords for with hymns.

Comment: Would you know of any examples? I think I would understand if better with an example

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR-exZTyfMo&ab_channel=Pourceuxquelelangagead%C3%A9sert%C3%A9s Note the pattern begins on different parts of a measure.